# how allow DataGridView allow paging In C# application

Tags: c#, datagridview

DataGridView.allow paging In C# application 
it possible to allow default pagination in Data grid view 
as same as we do in Datagrid 
any suggestion

Comment: DataGridView.allow paging In C# application it possible to allow default pagination in Data grid view as same as we do in Datagrid any suggestion http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewPaging.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView cannot perform paging by default. Take a look at some source codes over google, or this project who solves this problem:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/DataGridViewPaging.aspx

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take a look to below link it will help you, how to set paging and sorting for Datagridview..........
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx

Comment: Hello, jones take a look to above link..and you find a good article on it.

Answer (score 1):

DatagridView doesn't support paging by default. If you want it in there you'll need to implement it by yourself. the details of how to do that will depend on your underlying dataaccess technology